# Odoo 14 report styles and hieroglyphs

Tags: odoo, report

Please, help.

Chinese (Japanese, Korean) characters are displayed incorrectly in reports. Only these languages, the rest are displayed correctly

I am using Odoo 14 on Windows.

In order for CSS styles to be included in reports, I added the system parameter report.url (127.0.0.1:8069), but now Chinese characters are no longer displayed correctly (displayed in squares).

What can I do about it? Thanks.